# What effect if any does "Google Instant" search have on SEO and SEM?

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, marketing, sem

It been a little over a month since "Google Instant" has been released to the public, what effect if any does "Google Instant" search have on SEO and SEM based?

**RELATE LINK >> "Google Instant":**
http://www.google.com/instant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically speaking, long tail searches should see less traffic as users will be more likely to find, and click on, results before they get to finish typing in their entire search term. As a result those long tail searches will be less likely to happen and thus less able to deliver traffic.

As for SEM, it will [affect the amount of impressions you see in your Adwords campaigns](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/09/google-instant-impact-on-search-queries.html).

Comment: @John_Conde: Long-term I'm unable to see how compressing the market would be in Google's self interest. By influencing searches and driving AD unit sales over the long-tail, Google will building out progressive demand for keywords and decrease the level of entropy in the long tail's growth, driving up AD prices by managing supply and demand at the query level. Logic being that ADs are sold by the query, not by results of the query. What's you're "impression" of my spin on Google Instant objectives?

Comment: @John_Conde: Nice link by the way, though there's a end parenthesis in the URL at the very end that's breaking the link.

Comment: Google Instant shows more ads then before. That only helps them make more advertising revenue as more opportunities to click means more clicks. They don't need lots of searches to be done anymore when they can get more impressions from one search.

Comment: I think John is right on this.  And as for Google's self interest, just look at the cost per click difference between a 1, 2 or 3 word string and a longer one.  They're going to make a lot more money on ads now, no?

Comment: @binaryorganic - Main issue is that Google's goal is to increase impressions, seems to me more impressions does NOT equal more clicks. Example, I want to search for "toys" -- If I type "t" Google Instant shows "target, twitter, travelocity, tmz, t" -- "to" shows tour de france, toyota, top chef, toy story 3, to"... no Adwords are displayed until I get to "to" and they all have to do with "tour de france" -- if just impressions mattered Google would keep streaming content even after I stopped typing, they don't.

Comment: "Toys" is a very short search term and is a bad example. Try a more commonly used multi-word phrase. To continue where you started, do searches for "toy story". That's a great example of this in action. The ads change to better reflect the search term as you progress. Every impression is an opportunity for a click that didn't exist before.

Comment: right, but my point steps around the issue of impressions altogether to suggest that someone buying a link for the keyword "toy story" is paying several times more per click than someone buying a link for the keyword "toy story action figure."

Answer (score 3):

I would say the biggest impact this will have is it will give Google huge potential to influence keyword direction based on what they suggest to a user when mid-typing. Rather than an SEO finding keywords or niche keywords based on research, the strategy could consist of tailoring content to try and appear underneath the Google suggested combination of keywords. This would result in more websites chasing a smaller set of keywords, which in turn would of course make for even stiffer competition.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Google Instant Search is a big help to internet marketers / SEO specialists. Saves you time, you get an idea of what people are searching for and how to and how Not to structure their pages.

I created a small video about it at 
http://bloggerkhan.com/how-google-instant-search-affects-seo/164

See if it helps.